# window.unload should display a custom popup instead of alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to alert users about unsaved changes before they leave a page.But i dont want to use the default alert box for that . Suppose consider calling `showalertPopup()` Function displays the my designed alert box . How to replace it with the default alert box

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        $alertMsg = "Are you sure wanna leave this Page ?"
        return $alertMsg;
    };
```

Comment: `errorMessages` must return a string. That's said, you cannot use an alert box instead of the native prompt box

Comment: Changed ! errorMessages will return string only . Theres no way of repacing native prompt box ah ? Any jquery plugins like that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648522/custom-alert-and-confirm-box-in-jquery

This post can help you i think !

Comment: I am referring to my old answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23236794/3509874

Comment: @user3383301 jQuery is javascript. What cannot be done in javascript, cannot be done using jQuery

Comment: The easiest way is to hide and display a div instead of using an alert. then you can customise your div